# not able to execute nutch crawl command using php exec function

Tags: php, nutch

I have to run Nutch crawl commands using php exec but it shows

> "0 Error: JAVA_HOME is not set"

**The command works fine with terminal**. I have tried the below code in crawl.php where **apache-nutch-1.15** directory is placed.

```
exec('apache-nutch-1.15/bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls',$output);
```

and this gives the above mentioned error.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run Nutch you need the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set and pointing to the proper path (where your JVM is installed). This works on your terminal because you have this variable set already. You can check this with:

```
$ env | grep JAVA
```

When a new process is started with `exec` from PHP, this environment variable is not set because it is not a shell, you're only starting a process without any "shell environment". You can use the [`putenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) function to specify some environment variables before calling `exec`.

Comment: thank you jorge ,its worked and i have used putenv like u said, putenv('JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle'); the "JAVA_HOME is not set " error has gone. but now it shows "Generator: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/www/html/NutchSearch/apache-nutch-1.15/crawl/crawldb/.locked (Permission denied)". so i tried exec('chmod +x apache-nutch-1.15/bin/nutch'); but not worked

Comment: Most likely the user under which php is running cannot access/write the path where Nutch is persisting the data of the crawl.

Comment: once again thanks to you giving me clarification.And can you suggest me a solution to do this?

Comment: Apache Nutch has a (limited) REST API: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch_1.X_RESTAPI You could run this and using PHP interact with the API to start and (to some extent) configure the crawl.